# ConEmu: Open files in vim with ConEmu through File Explorer

Tags: vim, windows-explorer, gvim, conemu

Is it possible to open files by double clicking an associated file extension or through context menu with vim in a ConEmu tab?

Comment: Unclear. What are you clicking (where)?

Comment: @Maximus: I'd say a file associated with Vim (e.g. a `.txt` file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. Create a batch file, let's say `conemuvim.bat` and add its path into PATH variable
2. Assign desired file extensions to be opened with `conemuvim` (to do so, shift+click2 on a file -> open with -> choose default
3. Done.

Now, in `conemuvim.bat` you only need to add the following:

```
@echo off

start "ConEmu" "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" -cmd vim.exe "%1"
```

(surely enough, you need to change the path of the conemu and have `vim.exe` into your PATH)

That's all :)

// edit:
Obviously, this will work with any other console application. Considering this is only a rough mock-up, it may not work well if you need to open multiple files, vim command flags and so on, but it's surely a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it only opens up the ConEmu console for me without Vim or any error message.

Comment: If you type `vim` in a `cmd` window will start vim? Also, you updated the conemu path to match your system (e.g. maybe you are using 32bit version?)

Comment: Yes Vim will start anywhere I type `vim`. The path to ConEmu matches, otherwise that wouldn't start at all I guess.

Comment: I reset my config and now it's working. This answer works.